# Read Stata 14 unicode do file in Stata 13

Tags: unicode, stata

I edit and save a do-file in Stata 14 with unicode characters such as ö, Ö, ä, Ä, etc.

When someone else tries to open this do-file in Stata 13, the character is not displayed correctly (since Stata 13 does not support unicode).

After hours of searching a solution in the entire internet, this old 2015 post is the only existing post discussing this issue - but it does not offer a solution: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1300263-translate-stata-14-utf8-do-file-into-stata-13-or-earlier-do-file

How can I edit and save a do-file in Stata 14 with unicode characters and make this do-file readable in Stata 13?

PS:

- I cannot not have Stata 13 on that computer, so copying and pasting the do-file in a Stata 13 do-file editor then saving won`t work.
- If I edit with an external editor, it can't be read by Stata 14.
- unicode translate only translates from ASCII --> to unicode, but not in the other direction.

Comment: I don't think this can be done. Older programs can't know newer features.

Comment: Can Stata 14 (the newer program) save the do-file so that it`s readable by the older one (Stata 13)?

Comment: In principle, yes, if only because you can hand-edit the awkward characters. But as many Unicode characters don't have Stata-readable equivalents, I don't know a simple way to do this. I'd ask on Statalist: more people there deal with Unicode in Stata than watch Stata questions here.